# KendoUI ObservableObject: Set multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, observable

I'm using a kendo.data.ObservableObject, and want to change two attributes at once (so the change-event doesn't get fired twice). I'm not sure of the syntax (`background.set('id', backgroundId)` for a single attribute), and the documentation isn't of much help. Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set more than one attribute at once. You need to call the `set` method twice.

If you just want to avoid triggering the change event assign the attribute without using the `set` method:

```
model.foo = "foo" ; // won't trigger "change"
model.set("bar", "bar"); // will trigger "change"
```

Comment: So basically this would trigger the change event twice? Is there another way around this limitation? Writing a custom event?

Comment: A custom event would not prevent the change event from firing.

Comment: What's of particular interest is what happens during this event. We have a grid bound to an observable object, each row has a custom selector for a particular column that when changed raises an event which we capture which in turn updates various fields on the args.data object using the set method. It's unbelievably slow and there's absolutely no way around it. We're considering doing away with the observableObject, doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Hi if we simply click outside the grid then model.foo does not update

Comment: Just came here 10 years later to say this approach is still the best when dealing with ObservableObject. Just a reminder that if you don't call the set method at least once it wont refresh. So what I did was a simple assign and after all data is updated call the set method on a bogus property. :)